# how to run docker for newman with environment and global json

Tags: docker, newman

Tried adding docker for newman with below commands:

1. Pulling the image:docker `pull postman/newman_ubuntu1404`
2. ```
   sudo docker run -it --name newman postman/newman_ubuntu1404 newman run tests.json --environment ~/environments/staging.json -n 1 --globals ~/data/globals.json
   ```

   and it throw error

   ```
   Newman: Invalid command or parameter.
   ```

Example:

```
newman run my-api.json -e variables.json
```

Tried adding -v mount volume with docker but it doesnot work.

So how do I pass the tests, environment and globals JSON in docker.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the docker image with arguments only (without `newman`). The files are mounted into `/etc/newman`. Try

```
docker run --rm --name newman --volume ~:/etc/newman postman/newman_ubuntu1404 run tests.json --environment environments/staging.json -n 1 --globals data/globals.json
```

Comment: Ran it with command:sudo docker run --rm --name="newman" -v ~/tests/tests.json:/tmp/newman -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 run "collection url" --environment="staging.json", It throws unable to read data from file "staging.json"
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'staging.json'

though the path is correct and json file exists.

Comment: You have to mount the folder that contains `staging.json`. You need `--volume ~:/etc/newman`

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification:

```
docker run \
--rm \
-it \
# Mount local directory
-v `pwd`/test_folder:/etc/postman \
brandondoran/docker-newman -e test_folder/production.json collection.json
```

Reference: https://github.com/brandondoran/docker-newman